# OpenAI API error: "AttributeError: 'openai' module has no 'Thread' attribute"

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api

I'm developing a chatbot using **OpenAI's Assistants API** and facing an issue with integrating the `Thread` functionality. When trying to create a thread using `openai.Thread.create`, I encounter an AttributeError stating that the 'openai' module has no attribute 'Thread'.

Here's the code:

```
import openai

openai.api_key = "my_key"

def my_chatbot(user_input, assistant_id):
    thread_id = openai.Thread.create(assistant=assistant_id)["id"]

    openai.Message.create(
        thread=thread_id,
        role="user",
        content=user_input
    )

    run = openai.Run.create(
        thread=thread_id,
        assistant=assistant_id
    )

    messages = openai.Message.list(thread=thread_id)
    return messages["data"][-1]["content"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    assistant_id = "my_id"
    while True:
        user_input = input("Você: ")
        if user_input.lower() in ["sair", "fechar"]:
            break

        chatbot_response = my_chatbot(user_input, assistant_id)
        print("Chatbot:", chatbot_response)
```

The error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/felipestoker/PycharmProjects/chatbot/main.py", line 34, in <module>
    chatbot_response = chatbot_webjasper(user_input, assistant_id)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/felipestoker/PycharmProjects/chatbot/main.py", line 8, in chatbot_webjasper
    thread_id = openai.Thread.create(assistant=assistant_id)["id"]
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'Thread'
```

Comment: Please include the ful traceback error.  What version of OpenAI do you have installed?

Comment: Though this might help you https://community.openai.com/t/module-openai-has-no-attribute-thread/530342/3

Comment: @ewokx full traceback error updated in the question.
I tried this link, but it is not working.

Comment: That traceback isn't the traceback for the code you posted.  I don't see ```chatbot_webjasper``` mentioned in the posted code.

Comment: @weokx it is, I deleted for privacy.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this

https://github.com/rajib76/assistants/blob/main/assistants/llm_assistants/openai_assistants.py

This shows how to create thread and messages. This is part of the langassist package. If you are still not able to follow, please let me know. I will try to rewrite the program that you have above.

Comment: I am a beginner developer. It sounded difficult to me. In my case, I want to use Assistants API as a model. Because I have trained an Assistant to work with chatbot.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

**The method names you're trying to use don't work with the OpenAI Python SDK version `1.0.0` or newer.**

#### Solution

The following are the correct method names if you have the OpenAI Python SDK version `1.0.0` or newer:

- Create thread: `openai.beta.threads.create`
- Create message: `openai.beta.threads.messages.create`
- Create run: `openai.beta.threads.runs.create`
- List messages: `openai.beta.threads.messages.list`

See the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/assistants).

Also, I've made a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/F-KRs6vg4mM) on how to use the Assistants API and posted the [code](https://github.com/rokbenko/ai-playground/tree/main/openai-tutorials/2-Build_personal_math_tutor) on my GitHub profile.